# How do I verify if an equation is correctly re-arranged?

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

Let's say for pen and paper re-arrangement of some equation, sometimes getting a single step wrong and then wasting time on subsequent steps can be a large time sink.

My goal is to be able to verify each re-arrangement of an equation, to make sure each step I'm doing isn't illegal.

For example, given a base equation of x - ax^2 = 1, I'd like to re-arrange this as 1 - ax = 1/x. Note I don't want mathematica to solve for 1-ax for me using its own steps. I simply want to check whether my re-arrangement is correct or not. How could I do this?

Ideally in pseudocode, this would be something like:
"Given an equation x - ax^2 = 1, refactor as 1 - ax = 1/x". It should return a 'true' or 'false' or some other simple indicator as to whether this is a legal re-arrangement or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
expr1 = x - a x^2 == 1;
expr2 = 1 - a x == 1/x;
```

**1.** [`FullSimplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify.html)

```
FullSimplify[expr2, expr1]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

**2.** [`Equivalent`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Equivalent.html) + [`Resolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Resolve.html)

```
Resolve @ ForAll[{x, y, a}, x != 0, Equivalent[expr1, expr2]]
```

> ```
>  True
> ```

Comment: This appears to work perfectly for now, thanks!